# Python Pip Upgrade Error in Jenkins Docker environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have been trying to fix an issue in jenkins. Where i am getting this error related to pip upgrade which i am doing in docker file inorder to avoid RunTime error.
Following below are the logs i can see in jenkins.

```
Step 1/9 : FROM python:3.9
 ---> 60d390c1959b
Step 2/9 : COPY AWS_Lambda /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f503fa1503cc
Step 3/9 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d6c217ca3c17
Step 4/9 : RUN pip uninstall -y pygoogle
 ---> Running in f25e6a69e9b9
[91mWARNING: Skipping pygoogle as it is not installed.
[0m[91mWARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
[0mRemoving intermediate container f25e6a69e9b9
 ---> 436d544e2585
Step 5/9 : RUN pip install --upgrade pip
 ---> Running in 57790ab15a80
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (23.0.1)
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-23.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
[91mERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 160, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 247, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 419, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 92, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 481, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 348, in resolve
    self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 172, in _add_to_criteria
    if not criterion.candidates:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/structs.py", line 151, in __bool__
    return bool(self._sequence)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 155, in __bool__
    return any(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 143, in <genexpr>
    return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 97, in _iter_built_with_inserted
    candidate = func()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 206, in _make_candidate_from_link
    self._link_candidate_cache[link] = LinkCandidate(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 297, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 162, in __init__
    self.dist = self._prepare()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 231, in _prepare
    dist = self._prepare_distribution()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 308, in _prepare_distribution
    return preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(self._ireq, parallel_builds=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 491, in prepare_linked_requirement
    return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 536, in _prepare_linked_requirement
    local_file = unpack_url(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 166, in unpack_url
    file = get_http_url(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 107, in get_http_url
    from_path, content_type = download(link, temp_dir.path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/download.py", line 147, in __call__
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/progress_bars.py", line 52, in _rich_progress_bar
    with progress:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/progress.py", line 1169, in __enter__
    self.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/progress.py", line 1160, in start
    self.live.start(refresh=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/live.py", line 132, in start
    self._refresh_thread.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 899, in start
    _start_new_thread(self._bootstrap, ())
RuntimeError: can't start new thread
[0m[91m
[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.0.1 -> 23.2.1
[notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
[0mThe command '/bin/sh -c pip install --upgrade pip' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

I am expecting to not see this error and my jenkins pipeline should be running successully once this error resolves.

Comment: try with `python3 -m pip` instead of `pip`

Comment: @sahasrara62 i tried this as well. It didn't worked.

Comment: for command  ` '/bin/sh -c pip install --upgrade pip'` change it to `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip ` did you made this change also ?

Answer (score -1):

You may try two different approaches:

`python3 -m pip` or `pip3` instead of `pip`.

For some libraries `pip3` did work for me and regular `pip` did not. Note that `pip` is regularly used for **Python 2-** and `pip3` is supposed to be used in **Python 3+**.

**EDIT:** If you are working for some company there may be also problem with policies. Try to use personal hotspot from your phone without any **VPN**. It may also cause some issues.

Comment: "*Note that pip is regularly used for Python 2*" Not neccessary; `pip` is the default `pip` in any Python virtual environment, whether it's Python 2 or 3. "*use personal hotspot from your phone without any VPN*". In what way it could be related with the error "**can't start new thread**"?